# Upright and slanted \phi with newtxtext + newtxmath

Tags: math-mode, symbols, newtxmath, newtx, alphabeta

Just a curiosity.

> When I use an upright symbol with `alphabeta` package (I think also with another similar packages or with other tricks), I see that the tip of the vertical bar is inverted between slanted and vertical line. Why?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\begin{document}
\[
\upphi_s(W)=\phi_s(W)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you've posted. Specifically, whether or not the `alphabeta`  package is loaded (the `newtxmath` package also provides a macro called `\upphi`), the vertical line in `\upphi`  has constant thickness. I'm currently on a MikTeX system, `newtxtext` v1.65 2021/05/16, `newtxmath` v1.642 2021/03/27, and `alphabeta`  2.0 2020/10/30. FWIW, I'm getting the same result on an up-to-date MacTeX2021 system.

Comment: @Mico Don't worry because you are unable to reproduce the screenshot that I've posted :-)...Keep to calm :-)